# Ignite Transactional with DataStream's addData. possible?

Tags: java, transactions, ignite

we want to load bulk data into ignite cache, so we've used data streamer(stmr.addData) instead of cache.put(comparatively slow). Now want to apply transaction on my bulk load operation. which is happening with my data streamer case while same working with cache.put operation.

my code:

```
CacheConfiguration<String, Person> cacheConfiguration = new 
CacheConfiguration<>("PersonCache");
cacheConfiguration.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
IgniteTransactions transactions = ignite.transactions();
Transaction tx = transactions.txStart();
while (resultSet.next()) {
Persion person = new Persion();
persion.setName(name);
persion.setAge(age);
dataStreamer.addData(personKey, person);
}
tx.commit();

//while cache.put(personKey, person) is giving me transnational output
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to make DataStreamer use transaction in that fashion. The whole point of DataStreamer is to send data in bulk, not by one entry.

Why do you want this operation to be transactional? I think `StreamReceiver` or `allowOverwrite` will suit your needs better.

Comment: I need transactional here because I want to maintain Atomicity for my data load.  Means if the operation fails in the middle due to some exceptions then I don't want my cache with half data present. So I thought like to use tx.commit() at the end so that I can confirm i've committed my data load after all data inserted.
Also can u help how can achieve this by using  StreamReceiver .

Comment: I don't think you can do that and it would be pointless since you will lock down your whole cache for the duration. There are various strategies to do what you want, but none of them is universal.

Comment: But the same is working and giving my desired output while using with igniteCache.put() method. where I've loaded 30 lakhs data points and I can able to fetch that data from cache only after my transaction was committed in else case (transaction not committed yet & during the load time ) the cache fetch result is zero. so why cant we do with data streamer as well?

Comment: There would not be much of performance benefit over put() even if it was implemented.